# Reduce decimal places and add commas using vue js

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue js Data value that i get from a json. I use the json in a v-for prop to make Li for a side nav. One of the objects in the json it a long number. What would be the best way to parse it using vuejs within a for loop.

I have tried vue-numeric but could not get that to work properly because i am not using ecmascript 6 in this project and i just want to add it to the main vue script.

```
 data: {
            poolAPIData: {},


        },

<li v-for="(poolList, poolType) in poolConfig">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linux fa-fw"></i> {{poolType}}<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-third-level" v-for="pool in poolList">
                            <li style="font-size:90%;">
                                <a v-if="poolAPIData[pool.tag]" v-bind:href="pool.url"><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw"></i>{{pool.tag}} <br>HR|
                                    {{poolAPIData[pool.tag].hashrate}} <br>NHR|
                                    {{poolAPIData[pool.tag].network_hashrate}}<br>NWD|
                                    {{poolAPIData[pool.tag].difficulty}}



                                </a>


                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>


 this.poolAPIData = $.ajax({
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: 'https://coinstop.me/api/',
                    success: (data => this.poolAPIData = data)
            })
                ;
```

i need to parse the Difficulty argument to have 2 decimal places and commas every 3 digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [filter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html) that runs the given value through [`Number#toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString), with the `maximumFractionDigits` option set to `2`:

```
new Vue({
  // ...
  filters: {
    currency(amount) {
      const amt = Number(amount)
      return amt && amt.toLocaleString(undefined, {maximumFractionDigits:2}) || '0'
    }
  }
})

// usage in HTML: {{poolAPIData[pool.tag].difficulty | currency}}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    poolAPIData: {
      nul: {
        difficulty: null
      },
      str: {
        difficulty: "1234567.890123456789"
      },
      num: {
        difficulty: 1234567.890123
      }
    }
  },

  filters: {
    currency(amount) {
      const amt = Number(amount)
      return amt && amt.toLocaleString(undefined, {maximumFractionDigits:2}) || '0'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ poolAPIData['nul'].difficulty | currency }}</p>
  <p>{{ poolAPIData['str'].difficulty | currency }}</p>
  <p>{{ poolAPIData['num'].difficulty | currency }}</p>
</div>
```